# How do i substitue a string using Pure Python adb device.shell?

Tags: python, string, adb

I a using pure-python-adb

```
device.shell('input touchscreen tap 240 856')
```

Above works as it should.

something like

```
SomeStr = "\'" "input touchscreen tap " + str(476) + " " + str(421) + "\'"
device.shell(SomeStr)
```

does not work at all.
if i print SomeStr, it reads as 'input touchscreen tap 476 421'

Why cant i use a string in place of the written text?  out of ideas why this isnt working..
Any help most appreciated.

I have tried using a string.  Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: You're adding an extra set of quotes. Just... literally don't add the `\'` quotation marks to the outside. Those are entirely unnecessary.

Comment: Why not use something like `SomeStr = "input touchscreen tap " + str(476) + " " + str(421)`?

Comment: In your second example, the single quotes are literally _part of the string_, which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The single quotes are not passed to `adb` in your "working" command. Unclear why you added them.

Have you considered using f-strings? You don't need a separate string variable, only the coordinates.

```
x = 240
y = 856
device.shell(f'input touchscreen tap {x} {y}')
```